# Hello, currently I am trying to hide php extension of my subfolder called "games"

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have already hidden php extensions in the main root folder, here is the code below:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: You need to explain what your issue is. What happens?

Comment: and what is the problem? You didn't ask any question!

Comment: Hello, I have the following URL structure root_folder/subfolder/page.php, I want it to be like :  root_folder/page .  So I want to hide subfolder and file extension ("php"). How can I do it ?, I am novice in this kind of sphere, thank you !